# How to get amount of database records per month Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have the following Query in sequelize

```
let regMonth = [];

    let month = 1;  
while (month < 13) {

    const currMonth = await registrations.findAndCountAll({
      attributes: ['id'],
  where: {
    createdAt: {
      [Op.gte]: moment("0101", "MMDD").subtract((30 * month)-365, 'days').toDate()
    }
  }
})

regMonth.push(currMonth);

month++;


}
```

And it is supposed to create an array which contains the amount of Database records created in the respective months. And it works to some degree, but the resulting array looks like this:

```
[3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

but it is supposed to return

```
[0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

because I only added `3` records in Febuary and in no other month.

How can I fix this issue, or is there another more efficient way I could do this, possibly making the current Year irrelevant.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
createdAt: {
      [Op.gte]: moment("0101", "MMDD").add(month-1, 'months').toDate(),
      [Op.lt]: moment("0101", "MMDD").add(month, 'months').toDate(),
    }
```

Please keep in mind the timezone difference (if any) between created_at values in your DB and curren timezone of your service.